# Using additional request parameters in Twitter Premium Search API

Tags: matlab, rest, twitter

I am using the [Twitter API](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs.html) from Matlab, specifically by means of the [`twitter`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/datafeed/twitter.html) class from the [Datafeed Toolbox](https://www.mathworks.com/products/datafeed.html).

I have essentially followed the [example code](https://www.mathworks.com/help/datafeed/twitter.search.html#d117e61886) from the official documentation. I created a Twitter app in my Twitter developer page, and obtained its API keys and access tokens. With those I can use the Twitter **Standard search** API from Matlab:

```
c = twitter(consumerkey,consumersecret,accesstoken,accesstokensecret);
% The variables 'consumerkey' etc are defined as character vectors
s = search(c,tweetquery,'count',100); % this works
```

Now I want to use the **Premium search** API. This has [two endpoints](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/search/overview/premium#AvailableOperators) for accessing Tweets:

> - **30-day** endpoint: provides Tweets from the previous 30 days.
> - **Full-archive** endpoint: provides complete and instant access to Tweets dating all the way back to the first Tweet in March 2006.

In addition, the Premium API has [two tiers](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/search/overview/premium.html) of access:

> - **Free Sandbox** access that enables initial testing and development.
> - **Paid Premium** access that provides increased access.

The link above specifies the restrictions associated to sandbox as compared with paid access.

I am trying to use the **full-archive** endpoint with **sandbox** access. For that I had to create a [developer environment](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/basics/developer-portal/guides/dev-environments) on Twitter, which I named `dev`.

The `search` method in Matlab's `twitter` class (which worked for the Standard access, as described above) doesn't seem to work with the Premium access. But I noticed that `search` actually calls `getdata`, and the latter does work for Premium access as follows. First, the Premium access URL needs to be defined:

```
c.URL = 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/tweets/search/fullarchive/dev.json';
```

and then the following syntax works:

```
s = getdata(c,c.URL,'query','Jimi Hendrix'); % this works
```

I have also been able to add [operators](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/search/guides/premium-operators.html) within the query string, for example to specify a range of geographical positions or to restrict the search to tweets that contain images:

```
s = getdata(c,c.URL,'query','place:"Palo Alto"'); % this works
s = getdata(c,c.URL,'query','Robert Smith bounding_box:[-0.2 51.4 0.1 51.6]') % this works
```

However—and **this is my question**—, I haven't been able to use additional [request parameters](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/search/guides/integrating-premium) defined in the Twitter API to refine the search, such as `fromDate`, `toDate` or `maxResults`:

```
s = getdata(c,c.URL,'query','John Frusciante', 'fromDate', '201708130000') % doesn't work
s = getdata(c,c.URL,'query','Rob Scallon', ...
    'fromDate', '201708130000', 'toDate', '201708150000') % doesn't work
s = getdata(c,c.URL,'query','Michael Lemmo', 'maxResults', '20') % doesn't work
```

All of the above return an `HTTP/1.1 422 Unprocessable Entity` error.

Is my syntax not correct? Maybe the `fromDate` etc parameters have to be part of the query string? Or maybe the sandbox tier of the Premium search doesn't support those parameters?

---

<sup>For context, I [don't really know](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oRWf0.png) what all those terms like *endpoint*, *tier*, *developer environment* and *token* mean, but still I'd like to [make this work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vwT2C.jpg).</sup>

Comment: Going by the description at https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/search/api-reference/premium-search#DataParameters, what you call 'addition request parameters' are defined for requests of type `POST /search/:product`. These are HTTP POST requests, can you try using `postdata` (https://in.mathworks.com/help/datafeed/twitter.postdata.html) instead of `getdata`. Although their usage is almost identical but you'll need to send parameters as a JSOn object.

Comment: @pii_ke It works! Thank you. Care to post that as an answer so I can accept it? For instance `s = postdata(c,c.URL,'query','John Frusciante', 'fromDate', '201708130000')` works (exactly the same as in my question but with `postdata` instead of `getdata`)

Comment: Done.
It is good that identical call to `postdata` works. I think `postdata` handles conversion of parameters to proper format nternally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Going by the description at https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/search/api-reference/premium-search#DataParameters, what you call 'addition request parameters' are defined for requests of type `POST /search/:product`. These are `HTTP POST` requests, can you try using `postdata` (https://in.mathworks.com/help/datafeed/twitter.postdata.html) instead of `getdata`. Their usage is almost identical.